# uninitialized local variable 'a' used by VS2012 on the object of a template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

In VS2012, the below code doesn't compile, it says
`error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'a' used` on the line `A<int> b(a);`
I tested it in gcc4.4.7, it's fine.

I had thought something prevents the compiler to generate the default constructor, but it seems just an issue with VS2012. Why does it give this error, any explanation on how the compiler process the code?

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    T* p;
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    A<int> b(a);
}
```

Comment: `a.p` is uninitialized. The default constructor for raw pointers is to leave it uninitialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tested it in gcc4.4.7, it's fine.

In what sense do you think it's fine? You are never setting the value a.p so the code may compile, but it's still garbage data even with gcc.

By default, [C4700](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axhfhh6x.aspx) is a warning, not an error so you can get it to compile in the same broken way that gcc probably compiles it. You just have `/WX` set to treat warnings as errors, which good practice.